# Bootstrap 3 - parent nav element disabled

Tags: navigation

Let's say I have a menu which is structured like this:

-- About (`href="/about"`)
----- Company (`href="/about/company"`)
----- History (`href="/about/history"`)
-- Offer (`href="/offer"`)
-- News (`href="/news"`)
-- Contact (`href="/contact"`)

So the 'Company' and 'History' are children of the 'About' element. Now, Bootstrap automatically creates the dropdown and if I want to visit 'About' and click it, it only opens the dropdown containing the children. So I can't actually visit 'About' from the menu. How can I force the Bootstrap theme to prevent this behavior?

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

it took me ages but if you go to *menu-link.func.php* and take out line 33       `$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';`

works!!! took me like 3 weeks of reading :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a jQuery script to remove the href tab and disable the link.

```
$('#mainlink a').removeAttr('href');
$('#mainlink a').addClass('disabled');
```

Just to add another case scenario sometimes the drop-down is only offered on the sibling pages. On a Drupal 8 site you need to go into the parent menu item and enable the - 
Show as expanded (all languages)